# Bullet and equations or itemize and equation

Tags: equations

I am using the following command.

```
\documentclass{12 pt}{article}

\begin{document}

$\bullet$  $A = B$        
\end{document}
```

Here, I need to show the both bullet and equation by the number like A = B ....(1) on the same line. Is there anyway we can do this?

Comment: Why do you want a bullet?  DOn't you prefer a number?

Comment: As posted you just get `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` from the spurious `\\ ` commands. You need to remove all those. The bullet and the equation _are_ on the same line as you have posted, as you have used inline math `$`. What is your real question?

Comment: @Rajesh David is right.  Please check my answer which I intended to be as close to your code as possible

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You edited to fix the error, but now your posted code appears to answer your own question, the bullet and A=B are on the same line. Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: @ Davioud Thank you. I need to represent A = B by a equation number like A = B .......(1).

Comment: @Rajesh: Do you mean `\begin{equation}A=B\end{equation}`?

Comment: @Rajesh please check your code before posting, as it stands now it still generates errors as `[12pt]` has to be in square brackets.

Comment: . A = B...(1) (Bullet symbol at the beginning, A = B and then equation number). Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bullet\qquad  A = B
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting itemization with equations, a solution is simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $A=B$
\end{itemize}
%$\bullet$  $A = B$ \\        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow your code, this is what you should write:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

$ \bullet A = B$\\  % or

$ \bullet$ $A = B$      
\end{document}
```

But please bear in mind that this is not standard use of math mode